# Devise column confirmed_at no longer updates after rails 3.2 + devise 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

After upgrading to rails 3.2 and devise 2.0
and clicking the confirmation link sent by email or copied from console in development, the confirmed_at column does not get updated. So the result is that you can't login.

What would be the approach to fix this since nothing comes up in the logs, attributes accessible has confirmed_at included,so the column should be updateable.

Comment: I upgrade to this configuration too (with confirmable) and it is working fine. What is happening is that (on one side) the mail is sent properly, when you click on the link you are redirected to your server and it says "welcome abc@example.com", but the column on the DB is not updated?

Comment: yes thats correct, confirmation link is send out, when clicked it says "confirmed" and below that an alert " you have to confirm before login " then when login same error, the confirmed_at column isn't set.

Comment: You can start with very basic debugging, like trying to update the confirmed_at manually using Rails console. After that again clicking on the link, etc. and then update the question accordingly.

Comment: Also did you customize Devise, or you are using it as it is.

Comment: I created an rails vanilla application that tries to reproduce this issue with confirmable but I didn't get the problem you found (https://github.com/rodrigoflores/Devise-confirmed-at-test/blob/master/log/development.log#L409) . Can you please paste the log ? Or does the log is the same thing as if it worked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few axes for your troubleshooting.

At first (the obvious :-) ) that you have activated confirmable in the user model

```
devise : :confirmable
```

Then, check that the following columns are defined in your database and in your model (similar if you are on Mongoid, with a different type)

```
## Confirmable
t.string   :confirmation_token
t.datetime :confirmed_at
t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
# t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

And finally (I do not know it apply to you and making the issue) but there was a change in 2.0 regarding confirmable

> Besides, a few configuration options were renamed or removed:
>
> Devise.confirm_within was renamed to Devise.allow_unconfirmed_access_for;

What is then giving you the rails console for the new user just just crated?

Should give something like

```
User.last
 => #<User .... email: "youremail@example.com", confirmation_token: "abch76UfqHBBxHw97123", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: 2012-02-10 11:06:41 UTC, unconfirmed_email: nil, ....>
```

And the link you received (which you can also manually copy paste in the browser should be similar to (and consistent with the above confirmation token)

```
<p><a href="http://localhost:5000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=abch76UfqHBBxHw97123">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

The user in the console should be modified accordingly

```
User.last
 => #<User .... email: "youremail@example.com", confirmation_token:nil, confirmed_at: confirmed_at: 2012-02-10 11:28:04 UTC, confirmation_sent_at: 2012-02-10 11:06:41 UTC, unconfirmed_email: nil, ....>
```

If when you copy the link in the browser still does not work, can you copy the last lines of the logs?

the ones around

```
20:36:51 web.1     | Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=abch76UfqHBBxHw97123" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-10 20:36:51 +0900
20:36:51 web.1     | [127.0.0.1] Processing by Devise::ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
20:36:51 web.1     |  [127.0.0.1]   Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"abch76UfqHBBxHw97123"}
```

Comment: Can confirm all above to be correct. The last part in the logs states something strange though. Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=PAPe74HyVmRheFbaBAaw" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-10 16:35:16 +0100
Processing by ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"PAPe74HyVmRheFbaBAaw"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'PAPe74HyVmRheFbaBAaw' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms

Comment: I mean exactly the "Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms" that seems like some issue with CanCan presumable, I missed these parts of the log before so it seems I need to setup CanCan so I can make commits  to the User resource I guess, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

(I moved it to a diffent answer because it deserve it I think)

> {"confirmation_token"=>"PAPe74HyVmRheFbaBAaw"} User Load (0.4ms) SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.confirmation_token = 'PAPe74HyVmRheFbaBAaw' LIMIT 1 (0.2ms) BEGIN (0.1ms) COMMIT Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms

Are you using together with CanCan? That is a Cancan config issue!
If you remove CanCan it will probably work :-). Nevertheless, there is a elegant solution in the CanCan Wiki for this case.

Put the following in your ApplicationController

```
check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
```

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization

> **Conditionally Check Authorization**
>
> As of CanCan 1.6, the check_authorization method supports :if and :unless options. Either one takes a method name as a symbol. This method will be called to determine if the authorization check will be performed. This makes it very easy to skip this check on all Devise controllers since they provide a devise_controller? method.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?  
end
```

Comment: This seems indeed the way to go, only problem is when adding this code "This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check."

Comment: Did you added Cancan at the same time or you was using it before? What version are you using? `rails g cancan:ability` does the minimal generation required for you (adding basically an ability.rb file).

Comment: this error is 'strange', in the sense that putting `:unless => :devise_controller?` is equivalent to add `skip_authorization_check` to the default Devise controllers of the gem. (It requires a server restart) By any chance you are defining special controller for some of the Devise actions?

Comment: if you `rake routes`, this is the controller cancan is complaining `user_confirmation POST   (/:locale)/users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create`. As this controller is a `class Devise::ConfirmationsController < DeviseController` the check is skipped

Comment: that could be causing the issues yes i have a custom confirmations controller that uses the devise controller. how should i fix that? thx!

Comment: You are not deriving from "Devise::ConfirmationsController"? In this case, did you tried as it suggested the error "Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check"? at the top of you custom controller `class myConfirmationController [return] `skip_authorization_check` or alternatively, in Ability.rb you can set the abilities for MyConfirmationController as for any other controller. Personally, I would go for the former is cleaner.

Comment: I tried suggestions today to no avail. Now in every controller that has no Cancan support needed I have "   skip_authorization_check " (also the ones extending the devise ones like the Confirmation And registration controllers I use to add some custom changes to devise in my app ) In Application Controller I have "   check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller? ". Tried to create a new user tonight, still table column is not updated and error is see next reply.

Comment: Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=Gsp1jsCtfqhhwjxaH9es" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-14 23:07:14 +0100
Processing by ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"Gsp1jsCtfqhhwjxaH9es"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'Gsp1jsCtfqhhwjxaH9es' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms

Comment: Im getting tired of CanCan have other issues with it also So Think of Dishing it and use another way to authorize users, there must be better tools than CanCan. Any idea how I can fix this frustrating error? thx

Comment: `check_authorization` in `ApplicationController` is forcing CanCan on all controllers. that was a way to have the application to skip the checks on the Devise controller (which did not fix your issue unfortunately). As test, did you tried to remove the Custom Controller and verified that the confirmation is properly working? At least, you can drill down the behavior to a single method [Personally, I am a big fan of CanCan]

Comment: Thx, I also added the skip cancan code to the custom controllers extending the devise ones, but the problem still persists. Confirmation method seems to be throwing issues, so I try deleting my custom controller and see if that works out post back here

Comment: you do not need to delete your custom controller. If you just remove the entry on your routes, Devise will use the default controller ignoring yours.